# Некорректное считывание символа из файла

Tags: c++

Нужно чтобы программа открывала файл с текстом и выводила на экран вместо текста азбуку морзе. (переводило т.е., из текста буквенного в морзе). На деле выходит консоль, с какой-то закорючкой и все. В чем может быть проблема?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    char en;
    ifstream F;
    F.open("C:\\Users\Андрей\\Desktop\\123.txt");

    F>>en;

    cout<<en<<endl;

    switch (en)
    {
    case 'A': case 'a':cout<< ".-.-.-.-"; break;
    case 'B': case 'b':cout<< ".-.-.-.-"; break;
    case 'C': case 'c':cout<< ".-.-.-.-"; break;
    case 'D': case 'd':cout<< ".-.-.-.-"; break;
    case 'E': case 'e':cout<< ".-.-.-.-"; break;
    case 'F': case 'f':cout<< ".-.-.-.-"; break;
    case 'G': case 'g':cout<< ".-.-.-.-"; break;
    case 'H': case 'h':cout<< ".-.-.-.-"; break;
    case 'I': case 'i':cout<< ".-.-.-.-"; break;
    case 'J': case 'j':cout<< ".-.-.-.-"; break;
    case 'K': case 'k':cout<< ".-.-.-.-"; break;
    case 'L': case 'l':cout<< ".-.-.-.-"; break;
    case 'M': case 'm':cout<< ".-.-.-.-"; break;
    case 'N': case 'n':cout<< ".-.-.-.-"; break;
    case 'O': case 'o':cout<< ".-.-.-.-"; break;
    case 'P': case 'p':cout<< ".-.-.-.-"; break;
    case 'Q': case 'q':cout<< ".-.-.-.-"; break;
    case 'R': case 'r':cout<< ".-.-.-.-"; break;
    case 'S': case 's':cout<< ".-.-.-.-"; break;
    case 'T': case 't':cout<< ".-.-.-.-"; break;
    case 'U': case 'u':cout<< ".-.-.-.-"; break;
    case 'V': case 'v':cout<< ".-.-.-.-"; break;
    case 'W': case 'w':cout<< ".-.-.-.-"; break;
    case 'X': case 'x':cout<< ".-.-.-.-"; break;
    case 'Y': case 'y':cout<< ".-.-.-.-"; break;
    case 'Z': case 'z':cout<< ".-.-.-.-"; break;
    }
    system ("pause");
}
```

Comment: А если закомментировать `switch`, что выводится в `cout<<en<<endl;`?

Comment: 78 ошибок, вот что выводится

Comment: А, так оно не компилируется? Так бы и сказали. Тогда первую ошибку в студию!

Comment: @VladD, очевидно же, что он говорил о том, что ошибки появляются только если сделать как вы попросили - т.е. если только "закомментировать switch" )

Comment: @SergeyRufanov: Аааа! ОП закомментировал не весь `switch`, а **только одну строку**? (_бьётся головой об стенку_)

Comment: @VladD, видимо да. Стоящие в некорректном месте 52 токена 'case', плюс 26 токенов 'break' - и получается ровно 78 ошибок ))

Comment: Ну ладно, так и есть, если бы я бы не учился, а все умел, сюда бы не попал. Но к черту отговорки. Если закомментировать все, то выходит тот же символ.

Comment: А что будет, если здесь `F.open("C:\\Users\Андрей\\Desktop\\123.txt");` добавить ещё один обратный слэш после `Users` ?

Comment: Увидел уже, спасибо, поставил. Ситуация не изменилась. Проблема осталась

Comment: А если вынести файл за пределы кириллической директории? Например, в `c:\123.txt`. Возможно, кодировочка имени файла не совпадает. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/78963719/stackoverflow/cpp/cpp_reading_file.png

Answer (score 2):

Вероятнее всего, программа не получает доступ к файлу (некорректный путь, кодировка имени файла не совпадает с системной кодировкой и т.п).

Что же касается самого решения, то `switch` - не самый хороший вариант. Вот один из возможных вариантов:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>
#include "iostream"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    string symbols[] = {
        "AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "FF", "GG", "HH", "II", "JJ", "KK",
        "LL", "MM", "NN", "OO", "PP", "QQ", "RR", "SS", "TT", "UU", "VV",
        "WW", "XX", "YY", "ZZ"
    };

    char en;
    ifstream F;
    F.open("D:\\123.txt");

    while (F>>en)
    {
        cout << en << ": ";
        auto index = (en & 0xdf) - 0x41;
        string n = symbols[index];

        cout << n << endl;
    }

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

`& 0xdf` сбрасывает пятый бит и таким образом преобразует символы из нижнего регистра в верхний регистр. Далее из получившегося кода вычитается `0x41`, то есть код символа `A` - таким образом рассчитывается индекс в массиве.

P.S. Здесь задан диапазон *только* для 26 букв английского алфавита (a-z, A-Z) *(не пытайтесь подсунуть другие символы - для них нужно делать отдельную обработку)* и для наглядности печатаются как считанная буква, так и полученная строка из массива, которая, опять же, для наглядности, просто дублирует оригинальную букву.

P.P.S. В работоспособности можете убедиться, скачав небольшой [пример](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/78963719/stackoverflow/cpp/cpp_read_file.zip)

**upd:** Немного подробнее о том, как это работает. Если посмотреть на таблицу кодов ASCII, то можно увидеть, что код символа `A` - `40` (коды указаны в шестнадцатеричной системе), код символа `a` - `60`, а коды символов `Z` и `z` - `5A` и `7A`.

[image: ASCII]

Если посмотреть на эти значения в двоичном представлении, то можно увидеть, что они идентичны, за исключением только одного бита - пятого (нумерация идёт справа налево и начинается с нуля).

```
A 0x40 01000000
a 0x60 01100000

B 0x41 01000001
b 0x61 01100001

Y 0x59 01011001
y 0x79 01111001

Z 0x5A 01011010
z 0x7A 01111010
```

Как видно, у букв в верхнем регистре этот бит сброшен (равен нулю), а у букв в нижнем регистре этот бит установлен (равен единице).

В результате, для того, чтобы привести любой символ из нижнего регистра в верхний регистр, достаточно просто устанавливать в 0 значение пятого бита. Именно это и делается с помощью побитного "и":

```
en & 0xdf
```

Если посмотреть на двоичное представление `0xdf`, то можно увидеть, что у него установлены все биты, кроме пятого: `11011111`. Как пример, для символа `z` на двоичном уровне это выглядит примерно так:

```
  01111010 (0x7A)
& 11011111 (0xDF)
= 01011010 (0x5A)
```

Теперь нужно получить номер символа (от нуля до 25), чтобы обратиться к требуемому элементу массива. Для этого из кода просто вычитается код самого первого из возможных символов. В данном случае это символ `A` с кодом `0x41`:

```
0x41 (A) - 0x41 (A) -> 0
0x5A (Z) - 0x41 (A) -> 25
```

Что касается кириллицы в пути, то проблема не в самой кириллице. Как я уже писал, скорее всего, не совпадает кодировка. Например, система использует кодировку cp-1251, а в проекте используется utf-8.

[image: example]

Как видите, проблем с кириллицей нет.

Это настраивается в настройках проекта:

[image: settings]

Comment: спасибо конечно, но мы как раз проходили switch, так что я его более менее понимаю, но вот то что написали Вы не очень.

Comment: п.с Я уже нашел проблему, в строке адреса файла стоят русские буквы, вот он и регуется

Comment: Добавил в ответ подробности и решение, как обойти проблему с кириллицей в пути

Comment: Эта строчка `auto index = (en & 0xdf) - 0x41;` - просто вынос мозга. Почему не написать так: `auto index = toupper(en) - 'A';`? Врага запутать пытались?

Comment: @ixSci Я на плюсах лет 15 уже не писал, многие детали забываются и в три часа ночи (когда писал ответ) как-то не особо вспоминаются, так что извиняюсь.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю, вы считываете один символ из файла и выводите его на печать, после чего пытаетесь найти соответствие в `switch`.
Чтобы полностью прочитать файл, надо всё обернуть в цикл, который будет читать файл до конца:

```
//Что-то вроде такого
while (F >> en) {
    //тут switch
}
```

Касаемо закорючки ничего сказать не могу, поскольку не знаю, как она выглядит. Возможно, кодировки разные в файле и консоли. Или текст в файле русский.

Но вызывается она скорее всего:

```
cout << en << endl;
```

Comment: http://s016.radikal.ru/i336/1506/54/e3d3339a0fe4.jpg - скрин

Comment: А покажи первые символы из файла, который пытаешься зашифровать

Comment: 3 строчки всего:123                                                                                                            АВ

Comment: Странно. Цифры и английские буквы должны отображаться без проблем. Попробуй изменить в файле все на только английские буквы и, если все равно будет выводиться сбитая кодировка, то попробуй в настройках Visual Studio выставить ее в cp1251 или utf-8

Comment: Ничего странного, отображается символ с кодом 123 :)

Comment: Нет, я убрал 123, то же самое

Comment: в дебагере посмотрите, чему равен `en`. или так сделайте: `cout<<static_cast<int>(en)<<endl;`

Comment: в файле осталось АВ. Сделал как Вы написали, теперь он мне выдает в консоле: -52.

Comment: @Андрей, очевидно, что в Вашем файле какой-то мусор. -52 это 0xCC. Так что разбирайтесь с файлом, он у Вас должен быть в ASCII, чтобы всё работало нормально. Ну или UTF-8

Comment: А что в нем разбираться? Создал блокнот, в нем 2 буквы на англ.: А В. Что может быть не так?

Comment: Окей, хорошо, а как сделать так, чтобы программа читала обычный текст?

Comment: Что ты понимаешь под "обычный"? Русский или вообще любые буквы?

Comment: Английский текст.

Comment: Как я понял, проблема в том, что программа не воспринимает простой (английский) текст из блокнота?